# Статическая сборка под armv7l с использованием dockcross и curl

Tags: c++, curl, cmake

Имеется кросс компилятор dockcross и необходимо на моей машине скомпилировать бинарник с использованием curl и передать на целевую машину.
Скачиваю tar curl конфигурирую `./configure --prefix=директория/с/проектом --host=armv7l-musl --without-ssl --disable-shared` получаю в директории с проектом папки curl

`bin/`

`include/`

`lib/`

`share/`

CMakeLists

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(test)

# Указываем директорию, где находятся заголовочные файлы curl.
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include)

# Указываем директорию, где находятся статические библиотеки curl.
link_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)

# Создаем исполняемый файл из исходных файлов.
add_executable(MyExecutable test.cpp)

# Связываем исполняемый файл с библиотекой curl.
target_link_libraries(MyExecutable ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/libcurl.a)
```

Далее ввожу команды dockcross `./dockcross-linux-armv7l-musl cmake --build build_arm/`  и `./dockcross-linux-armv7l-musl cmake --build build_arm/`, получаю ошибку:

```
/usr/xcc/armv7l-linux-musleabihf-cross/bin/../lib/gcc/armv7l-linux-musleabihf/11.2.1/../../../../armv7l-linux-musleabihf/bin/ld: cannot use executable file '/work/lib/curl-armhf' as input to a link
```

Скачивал файлы с https://github.com/moparisthebest/static-curl для `curl-armv7` и `curl-armhf`, пытался использовать с dockcross  с g++ не получается.

Конфигурация целевой машины:

```
armv7l
5.5.0-g250b4e5503d1-dirty
  Tag_CPU_name: "7-A"
  Tag_CPU_arch: v7
  Tag_CPU_arch_profile: Приложение
  Tag_ARM_ISA_use: Yes
  Tag_THUMB_ISA_use: Thumb-2
  Tag_FP_arch: VFPv3-D16
  Tag_ABI_PCS_wchar_t: 4
  Tag_ABI_FP_rounding: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_denormal: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_exceptions: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_number_model: IEEE 754
  Tag_ABI_align_needed: 8-байтовый
  Tag_ABI_align_preserved: 8-байтовый, за исключением ответвления SP
  Tag_ABI_enum_size: int
  Tag_ABI_VFP_args: VFP registers
  Tag_CPU_unaligned_access: v6
arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110
 ldd --version
ldd (Debian GLIBC 2.31-13+deb11u6) 2.31
```